# Notation for l1-coherence of a matrix

Tags: vector-spaces, notation

I am currently reading Foucart and Rauhut's A Mathematical Introduction to Compressive Sensing, and I have some issues understanding some of the notation with respect to the $\mathcal{l}_1$-coherence.

Let $A \in \mathbb{C}^{mxN}$ be a matrix with $\mathcal{l}_2$-normalized columns $a_1,...,a_N$. The $\mathcal{l}_1$-coherence function $\mu_1$ of the matrix $A$ is defined for $s \in [N - 1]$ by

$\mu_1(s) = \max_{i\in [N]} \max{\{ \sum_{j \in S} | <a_i,a_j> |, S \subset [N],  \mathrm{card}(S)=s, i \not\in S \}}$

I just cannot wrap my head around how to interpret the double maximization here. Because what does the right max term maximize over without the $i$-index, how would the sum of inner products be maximized without maximizing over $i$?

Or do I read the notation from the wrong direction?

Comment: Are you sure you reproduced the formula correctly? The vertical bar after $Sigma_{j \in S}$ looks suspicious.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin Yes you are right, I added the missing vertical bar. Thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define for each $i$ and $s$ the set
$$
  {\cal F}(i,s) = \bigl\{ S \mid S \subset [N], \operatorname{Card}(S) = s \text{ and } i\not\in S \bigr\} 
$$
in order to rewrite your formula
$$
\mu_1(s) = \max_{i\in [N]} \max{\left\{ \sum_{j \in S} | \langle a_i,a_j \rangle |, S \subset [N],  \mathrm{card}(S)=s, i \not\in S \right\}}
$$
as follows
$$
\mu_1(s) = \max_{i\in [N]} \max_{S \in {\cal F}(i,s)}{\sum_{j \in S} | \langle a_i,a_j \rangle | }
$$
which should make clear how the two successive max are computed.

Comment: Oh so it is two max because there are two variables being maximized over? I think my notation may be sloppy as I usually use one max for multiple variables.
From what I understand here we first choose an `i`, then we create a set S that does not contain `i`. Would that be the correct intuition here?

Comment: To be more precise, you first choose an $i$ and then you consider the collection of all sets $S$ of size $s$ not containing $i$. To each such $S$, you attach the quantity $\sum_{j \in S} | \langle a_i,a_j \rangle|$ and then you take the max of these quantities. Finally, you take the max over $i$.

Comment: Cheers, that makes good sense.

Comment: You're welcome.